# lookup index value in a char table

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I am trying to find the index number, by looking through an array, but I can't use a loop. Is it possible?

I have attached the code to do this with a loop.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const char digits[] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', \
'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', };

int find_index(string str);

int main()
{
    string str = "A";
    cout << find_index(str) << endl;

}

int find_index(string str)
{
    // using a loop, in this case for loop.
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 16 ; i++)
    {
        // cout << digits[i] << endl;
        if ( digits[i] == str[0] )
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Is it possible to do the same thing without a loop?

Comment: Why? You can force the compiler to unroll the loop, and generate a lot of `if`s if the array size is known at compile time.

Comment: Without handwritten loop? Yes, you can call `std::find` (or better - `std::string::find`), for example. With no loops whatsoever? Yes, you can use sketchy techniques like `goto` and such, but I think that's not the point of the assignment you've been given.

Comment: `, \ ` isn't necessary BTW, you can omit the `\ `

Comment: Should it work with this array or any particular array. In former case it can be done with four comparisons. Aslo if you need to check if character is alphanumerical, there is standard function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to substitute the array for a string literal

```
const char *digits = { "0123456789ABCDEF" };
```

and to use the standard C function `strchr`. For example

```
size_t find_index( char c )
{
    const char *digits = { "0123456789ABCDEF" };

    c = std::toupper( ( unsigned char )c );

    const char *p = std::strchr( digits, c );

    return p == nullptr ? -1 : p - digits;   
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

size_t find_index( char c )
{
    const char *digits = { "0123456789ABCDEF" };

    c = std::toupper( ( unsigned char )c );

    const char *p = std::strchr( digits, c );

    return p == nullptr ? -1 : p - digits;   
}

int main()
{
    std::string s( "0123456789abcdef" );

    for ( char c : s )
    {
        size_t i = find_index( c );

        if ( i == size_t( -1 ) )
        {
            std::cout << "c is not a valid digit\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << c << ": " << i << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
0: 0
1: 1
2: 2
3: 3
4: 4
5: 5
6: 6
7: 7
8: 8
9: 9
a: 10
b: 11
c: 12
d: 13
e: 14
f: 15
```

A more strict function implementation (that excludes the character `'\0'` ) can look the following way

```
size_t find_index( char c )
{
    const char *digits = { "0123456789ABCDEF" };

    const char *p = nullptr;    

    if ( c != '\0' )
    {
        c = std::toupper( ( unsigned char )c );

        p = std::strchr( digits, c );
    }

    return p == nullptr ? -1 : p - digits;   
}
```

Another way is to use standard algorithms.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

size_t find_index( char c )
{
    static const char digits[] = 
    { 
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 
    };

    auto it = std::find( std::begin( digits ), std::end( digits ), std::toupper( ( unsigned char )c ) );

    return it == std::end( digits ) ? -1 : std::distance( std::begin( digits ), it );   
}

int main()
{
    std::string s( "0123456789abcdef" );

    for ( char c : s )
    {
        size_t i = find_index( c );

        if ( i == size_t( -1 ) )
        {
            std::cout << "c is not a valid digit\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << c << ": " << i << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

The output will be the same as shown above.

As the array is sorted you can also use the standard algorithm `std::lower_bound` instead of `std::find` for ASCII characters (not for EBCDIC).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (loopsAllowed == false) {
    useRecursion();
}
else {
    useLoops();
}
```

This is a pretty standard way of doing things if you have odd requirements for your school project. One thing I would avoid is using `goto` to jump to previous sections of code. This is literally looping.

Also, anything that is using loops is technically possible with recursion, given enough stack memory.